# What is Kanchō (カンチョー)? Do boys really do that in Japan?

Tags: slang, culture

My friend and I were talking about pranks (upcoming April Fool's Day in Canada) and she taught me a crude prank that apparently some kids in Japan do to each other called a カンチョー ("Kanchō"), where they make a gun shape with both hands and stick their fingers right up some poor kids bum.

[image: Kanchō]

I was curious cause it sounds a lot like the famous "wedgie" the boys over here do to prank or bully each other, where they pull on someone's underwear to painfully "wedge" it up the buttcrack. Is Kanchō the Japanese equivalent of this cruel prank? Is it as widespread and well-known as the wedgie is here? Do boys in Japan also give wedgies (I've never seen anyone give a Kanchō here)? I guess I'm surprised at the similarities between cultures on how kids like to mess with each other!

[image: Wedgie]

Comment: It's that and yes, they do, but do you have any questions about the Japanese language or this particular word?

Comment: Thanks, maybe does the word have any meaning? Or is it just a slang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

カンチョー is 浣腸 (literally 浣【かん】 = wash, 腸【ちょう】 = intestine) in kanji, and "enema" in English. So its origin is completely different from that of wedgie. While both pranks involve someone's buttocks, there are no further similarities beyond that. Wedgie itself is not commonly recognized as a typical prank in Japan.

カンチョー was very popular among young Japanese boys at least several dozens years ago. I learned the word as a prank name first when I was 5 or 6, and learned its original purpose (enema) much later. Still, this may not be equally common today...

Comment: thanks! that makes total sense.